# How to change the dot's color or fill the dots in varImpPlot function to make it more clear?

Tags: r, machine-learning, plot, random-forest

I have used Random Forest and tried to plot the important features using **varImpPlot()**

```
varImpPlot(random_fit, type = 1, main = "RF Feature Importance")
```

and the dots are not really clear to the eye, so how can i change it to vertical lines, or maybe fill those dots?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the `varImpPlot` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/varImpPlot), the function can accept also:

> ...     Other graphical parameters to be passed on to [`dotchart`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/dotchart).

For example, you can fill the dots with `bg`:

```
library(randomForest)

set.seed(4543)
data(mtcars)

mtcars.rf <- randomForest(mpg ~ ., data=mtcars, ntree=1000, keep.forest=FALSE,
                          importance=TRUE)

varImpPlot(mtcars.rf, bg = "skyblue")
```

[image]

increase their size with `cex`:

```
varImpPlot(mtcars.rf, bg = "skyblue", cex=2)
```

[image]

or change their type with `pch`:

```
varImpPlot(mtcars.rf, bg = "skyblue", cex=2, pch=22)
```

[image]

AFAIK, you can not add vertical lines (asking for `type="l"` will result in an error); this is maybe due to the fact that, under the hood, the base R graphics function `dotchart` used does not support lines.